# fetch and async/await without try/catch

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I'm trying to get async await to work without try/catch

```
  return await fetch(url, options)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(err => {
      throw new Error(err)
    })
```

Here is how I make the call:

```
    const response = await makeApiRequest('/reset', {
        password: password1,
        code
    }, {
        noauth: true
    }).catch(err => {
        debugger;
        msg = err.message;
    });

    if (response) {
        navigateTo('/');
    }
```

The problem is none of the catch blocks are working. The code is expired and serving a 401.

Comment: why are you using async/await without try/catch? error handling with async/await implies using try/catch

Comment: by the way ... a 401 response won't trigger an error/rejection in fetch

Comment: also, `return await fetch` should just be `return fetch` - in an async function you don't need to `return await` a promise

Comment: you could probably do something like `.then(res => res.ok ? res.json() : Promise.reject(res.statusText))` ... res.ok is only true for response.status = 200->299

Comment: I read this article on medium about using async/await w/o try/catch. https://itnext.io/async-await-without-try-catch-in-javascript-6dcdf705f8b1

Comment: Ahh, right, those examples handle errors in `.catch` ... and **don't** throw a new one that won't be handled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I got to work:

```
  return fetch(url, options)
    .then(async res => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        const err = await res.json()
        throw err.message || res.statusText
      }

      return res.json()
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw new Error(err)
    })
```

You can call it like this:

```
        const response = await myFetch('/forgot', {
            email
        }, {
            headers: {
                'x-contact': 'hello@puump.com'
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            msg = err.message;
            return;
        });

        if (response) {
            push('/');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch API fails only if it can't make a request. And if it can, fetch will be executed successfully even if it has a bad status.

Because `throw new Error(err)` never been called, it just be call when you try to parse a `invalid string content` to a json object (`res.json()`). I guest, in 401 case your server return a valid json string like `{message: "Unauthorized"}`, then `res.json()` working fine, and does not have any error has been throw.

If you want to catch http error, then `http status code` of `res` object is a right way:

```
  return await fetch(url, options)
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status >= 300) { // error http status code range
        throw new Error(res.status) // throw a error to the catch block
      }
      return res.json();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw new Error(err) // catch and throw to the error of previous `.then` block
    })
```

Then try again.

Comment: How should I serve a 401? This doesn't work either. I can get res.status but I want the text too.

Comment: @chovy `How should I serve a 401?` what do you mean how? you respond with 401 status ... `but I want the text too` huh? do you mean res.statusText?

Comment: *just for `res.json()` 's error. Not for http error* that's where you are wrong - that catch will catch the error thrown  in the .then - because that's how Promise chaining goes